# Get value for dynamic vars.put

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

If I set the put key value to the dynamic `i` value in the graph (this is a requirement),

When I get `vars.get("i")`, I can only get the value aaa2 when i=2

I want to get all the values(aaa1 and aaa2), what should I do?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view multiple values you need to save multiple variables by changing your `vars.put` line to:

```
vars.put("i" + i, a);
```

and then get it using `${i[number]}` as:

```
${i0} ${i1} ${i2}
```

Another option is to concatenate values to variable `${i]` similar to

```
vars.put("i" , (vars.get("i") == null ? "" : vars.get("i")) + a);
```

Also change your Beanshell sampler to JSR223 Sampler according to JMeter [Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

> we advise switching from BeanShell to JSR223 Test Elements

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem in time! ：）